# Change the name of my main account - how can I do that?

Tags: login, accounts

I had somebody to reinstall my computer and he gave a name to my main account that does not please me. I want to change it. How could I possibly do that?

Comment: are you talking about username or Name of the user?? what is your 0perating System??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way for your case I think would be to just create a new user from the settings and start using the new one (optionally delete the old user later)

If you have a lot of data saved already and you **must** change the name you can follow these steps [here](https://www.hepeng.me/changing-username-and-hostname-on-ubuntu/)